# How to check if a particular view is currently focussed in Android

Tags: android, view

In my android app
I need to check whether a particular view is focussed.
Now I found the getCurrentFocus() function in Activity class
but this returns a View Object.

How can I compare and check whether this returned View is same as the one in question.
I mean there is no getName() function here.
So after getting the View object, how can I compare to check which View class is this ?

Comment: You can use `hasFocus ()` of view. You just need to check each focusable view using this method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `View.isFocused()` method tells whether the view in question is focused or not.

```
if (myView.isFocused()) {
    // your code
}
```

If you still want to use the getCurrentFocus() method, you can simply check:

```
View focusView = getCurrentFocus();
if (myView == focusView) {
    // your code
}
```

Or else, you can compare your views by id.

```
View focusView = getCurrentFocus();
if (focusView != null && myView.getId() == focusView.getId()) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Works, but I'm getting Method invocation getId may produce java NullpointerException

Comment: @CGR Well, isFocused() is the preferred way to go here. getCurrentFocus() can return a null view, so you should do a null check first if you decide to use getId().

Comment: Updated answer to do null check. Thanks @CGR.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the getId() method I guess?

e.g.

```
getCurrentFocus() == R.id.myView;
```

Answer (score 0):

getCurrentFocus() on the parent view

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29

Answer (score 0):

No need for getName(). Just use the == operator. See:

```
View myView = findViewById(...);

if (activitygetCurrentFocus() == myView)
    // ha focus

}
```

Another option, one I usually prefer, is to set a focus listener for the views you are interested in monitoring:

```
myView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if (hasFocus) {
               // got focus logic
          }
    }
});
```